# Instafeed.js - how to filter out or exclude specific image or user?

Tags: javascript, instagram, instafeedjs

I do understand that filter is being used to display more specific results. But is there a way that I can use it to exclude a specific user or image instead? Or do instafeed.js have another option for me to do this?

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
      target: 'instafeed',
      get: 'tagged',
      tagName: 'hashtag',
      limit: '10',
      sortBy: 'most-recent',
      resolution: 'standard_resolution',
      clientId: 'xxxxx', 
      template:'<img class="item" src="{{image}}">',
      filter: function(image) {
        //filter to exclude specific user
      }
    });
```

Appreciate any feedbacks.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you return `false` from the filter function, it will exclude the image from the results.

So to block images from a specific user, you can check the `image.user.username` property:

```
filter: function(image) {
  var blockedUsernames = [
    'reallybaduser',
    'otherreallybaduser'
  ];

  // check for blocked users
  for (var i=0; i<blockedUsernames.length; i++) {
    if (image.user.username === blockedUsernames[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

You can expand the filter function to check *any* property of image. So if you know a specific `id` of an image to block, you can check that property as well.

Comment: Sorry for responding late, but thanks for your prompt reply. The above code works for me! What if I want to exclude a specific image ID instead?

Comment: If you know the specific id, then you would check against it using `if (image.id === "THE_ID") { return false } else { return true }`, and replace THE_ID with the id you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Did Stevens answer solved your problem soulefay?

It does not work for me =/. Tested with model.user.username (which I use when I print out the uploaders username) as well but that did not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                var feed = new Instafeed({
                  get:'tagged',
                  tagName: 'horizon',
                  clientId: 'xxxxxxx',
                  limit:'16',
                  sortBy: 'most-liked',
                  resolution:'low_resolution',
                  template: '<img src="{{image}}" class="imagen" <p>Likes: {{likes}} User: {{model.user.username}} </p> ',
                /*  filter: function(image) {
                      var blockedUsernames = [
                        'reallybaduser',
                        'otherreallybaduser'
                      ];

                      // check for blocked users
                      for (var i=0; i<blockedUsernames.length; i++) {
                        if (image.user.username === blockedUsernames[i]) {
                          return false;
                        }
                      }

                      return true;
                    }, */
                  after:function(){
                    var images = $('#instafeed').find('a');
                  }
                });

                feed.run();

                /*==== GET MORE PICTURES.. ======*/
                $(function() {
                      $("#load-more").click( function()
                           {
                             feed.next();
                           }
                      );
                });
             </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In reply to Dahak, Steven's code works for me! Here's the full code on my website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'hashtag',
        clientId: 'xxxxxxxx',
        template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="http:{{image}}" class="insta" /></a>',
        limit: 20,
        filter: function(image) {
            var blockedUsernames = [
            'baduser',
            'otherreallybaduser'
            ];

            // check for blocked users
            for (var i=0; i<blockedUsernames.length; i++) {
               if (image.user.username === blockedUsernames[i]) {
                 return false;
               }
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
    feed.run();

</script>
```

Did you exclude the comment tag `/*` and `*/` when you test your code?

Sorry, I've limited javascript knowledge. =/